# What is "hydrostatic uplift pressure"?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, fluid-statics, building-physics

I was reading Wikipedia about the [St. Francis Dam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Francis_Dam) and came across this sentence.

> Water that collected in the drainage pipes under the dam to relieve
>   the hydrostatic uplift pressure was carried off in this manner as
>   well.

What is hydrostatic uplift pressure? The word "uplift" in particular confuses me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go down further into the article, you will find this:

> Uplift, called such as it tends to lift the dam upward, a condition which although many designers and builders of dams had become aware of by the late 1890s to early 1900s, was still not generally well understood or appreciated.

In essence, the dam is lifted by the water seeping under it from the reservoir.